# Show $p^2 + pq$ is not a perfect square for primes $p,q$

Tags: prime-numbers

I have the following proof:

Suppose it was a perfect square, then $\exists k$ such that $p^2 + pq = k^2$.

We can rewrite this as $pq = k^2 - p^2 = (k - p)(k + p)$. Since $p$ is a prime number, it must divide either $(k - p)$ or $(k + p)$. However, if $p$ divides $(k - p)$, then $(k + p)$ must be a multiple of $q$, which is not possible since $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers. Similarly, if $p$ divides $(k + p)$, then $(k - p)$ must be a multiple of $q$, which is also not possible. Therefore, our assumption that $p^2 + pq$ is a perfect square leads to a contradiction, and we can conclude that $p^2 + pq$ is not a perfect square.

Is this proof correct? It feels a little weird and I don't know why

Comment: Why can't $k+p$ be a multiple of $q$?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't understand why from $p^2 + pq = nk^2$ you ended up with an equation without the letter $n$: $pq = k^2 - p^2$. Where is the variable $n$? Maybe that is why it seems weird.

Comment: The OP does not use $nk^2$ but rather $k^2$ for the rest of the answer. I think this is just a typo.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought at first, thanks

Comment: If $p^2+pq=k^2,$ then $k$ is divisible by $p.$ Hence $pq$ is divisible by $p^2,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc how do we go from $p \mid k$ to $p^2 \mid pq$?  I see the contradiction but not the steps

Comment: @Jeff: I suggest you spend a little time trying to work it out (it's not that difficult) instead of immediately asking for more help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: you also have to rule out the case $q=p$ (which would mean that $pq$ _is_ divisible by $p^2$).

Comment: @TonyK I took for granted that $p\neq q.$ If $p=q$ then $2p^2$ is not a perfect square as the multiplicity of  the factor $2$ is either $1$ or $3.$

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your proof-checking question, as I am not too fast at that.  However, I would like to share with you this somewhat elegant proof.

Consider that:

$$
p^2 + pq = p(p + q) = k^2 \implies p \mid(p+q) \ \ \text{ in order to have a square}
$$

But $pz = p + q \implies p \mid q$.  Therefore $p = q$ necessarily, as distinct primes are coprime.

But if $p = q$ then in our original equation, we'd have:

$$
p^2 + p^2 = 2p^2 = k^2
$$

But $\Omega(2p^2) = 3$ while $\Omega(k^2) = 2\Omega(k) \in 2\Bbb{Z}$ (is an even number).  $\blacksquare$

---

Where $\Omega : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}\cup 0$ is from number theory and counts (including multiplicities) the prime factors of a number.  So $\Omega(9) = 2$, $\Omega(7) = 1$, $\Omega(24) = \Omega(2^3 \cdot 3) = 4$, etc.  It is completely additive so $\Omega(k^2) = \Omega(k) + \Omega(k) = 2\Omega(k)$.  A simpler way would be just to note that there always needs to be an even number of each prime dividing a square number.